# Recursive function for clearing zeros in an array/string

Tags: javascript

I need a function where I can clear off the zeros which appears at the beginning of my string, basically something like `'0000213'` in javascript. I just want the `'213'` and not the zeros. Here is the code that I have written but theres some problem with the array length in the for loop, can someone please help me with this. https://jsfiddle.net/066by2cv/3/

Comment: `Number('0000213');`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution.

```
'0000213'.replace(/0+/,'');
```

or

```
Number('0000213').toString();
```

or just

```
+'0000213' + ''
```

Comment: Thanks for the above solutions!

Answer (score 0):

Although already answered by @Tresdin, in case you really want your function, you can use

```
var str = '0003';

function Iterate(val) {
  var start = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < val.length; i++) {
    if (val.charAt(i) == '0') {
      start = i;
    }
  }
  return val.substr(start+1);
}

var re = Iterate(str);
alert(re);
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This gave a solution for me.